# Search Button fails with repeated searches

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong in the code, the search button only worked once and second time onwards it's not working?

Apex Code

```
public void showAccounts(){
    system.debug('Entethere=====');

    string strQuery = 'select id,name,(select id,Email from contacts where Receives_Maintenance_Notifications__c=true) from account ORDER BY Name ASC';
    //strSearchBy = 'Name';
    if(strSearchBy!=null && strSearchBy!=''){
        strQuery = strQuery+ ' where '+strSearchBy+ '=\''+strSearchText+'\'';  
         strQuery = strQuery+ ' where '+strSearchBy+ '=\''+strSearchText+'\'';  
    }
    system.debug('strQuery===='+strQuery);
    list<Account> lstAccount =DataBase.Query(strQuery);
    lstWrapper.clear();
    for(account objAccount :lstAccount){
        system.debug('objAcc====='+objAccount);
        if(objAccount.contacts.size()!=0){
            AccountWrapper objWrapper = new AccountWrapper();
            objWrapper.AccountRecord = objAccount;
            objWrapper.numberOfContacts = objAccount.contacts.size(); 
            lstWrapper.add(objWrapper); 

        }  
    }
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:inputText value="{!strSearchText}"/>        
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!showAccounts}"/>
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstWrapper}" var="vrAccount">
         <apex:column headerValue="Account">
         <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!vrAccount.bSelectedrecord}"/>
         </apex:column> 
         <apex:column value="{!vrAccount.AccountRecord.name}"/>   
         <apex:column value="{!vrAccount.numberOfContacts}" headerValue="Number of Contacts"/>   
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

> unexpected token: where
>
> Error is in expression `'{!showAccounts}'` in component `<apex:commandButton>` in page `emailtool: Class.EmailToolController.showAccounts`: line 52, column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting. Also I believe you should have the ORDER BY part of the query should be the last part of the query. From your code you are adding a where clause after the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: unexpected token: where
Error is in expression '{!showAccounts}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page emailtool: Class.EmailToolController.showAccounts: line 52, column 1

An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Comment: Hey Dan, Thank you! Got it, its because of ORDER BY clause.

Comment: No Problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: @DanKowalski, you should write an answer with a little more details than just these comments.

Comment: @Svi try to include error codes in your questions body, not the subject. I've fixed your formatting and edited your error code into the body of your question. Next time, try to [edit] the question instead of adding more details via comments. Try to use more descriptive tags than [error] too, few people use that tag, so less people will see your question.

Comment: Ok. but ORDER BY clause is not working if I put it after where clause, Could you please let me know where should I include ORDER BY?

Comment: A trick you can use is the look at the logs in your developer console and try to past the query into the query editor and see if you get any rows or errors back since you are sending the query to the debug log.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your SOQL query should look something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%A' ORDER BY Name
```

Currently your code creates a query that has the incorrect syntax. The query your code creates will look something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Id FROM Account ORDER BY Name WHERE Name LIKE '%A'
```

This is incorrect because the ORDER BY clause should be the last part of the query.

So your code should look something like the below:

```
public void showAccounts(){
    system.debug('Entethere=====');

    string strQuery = 'select id,name,(select id,Email from contacts where Receives_Maintenance_Notifications__c=true) from account ';
    //strSearchBy = 'Name';
    if(strSearchBy!=null && strSearchBy!=''){
        strQuery = strQuery+ ' where '+strSearchBy+ '=\''+strSearchText+'\'';  
         strQuery = strQuery+ ' where '+strSearchBy+ '=\''+strSearchText+'\'';  
    }

    strQuery = strQuery + ' ORDER BY Name ASC';
    system.debug('strQuery===='+strQuery);
    list<Account> lstAccount =DataBase.Query(strQuery);
    lstWrapper.clear();
    for(account objAccount :lstAccount){
        system.debug('objAcc====='+objAccount);
        if(objAccount.contacts.size()!=0){
            AccountWrapper objWrapper = new AccountWrapper();
            objWrapper.AccountRecord = objAccount;
            objWrapper.numberOfContacts = objAccount.contacts.size(); 
            lstWrapper.add(objWrapper); 

        }  
    }
}
```

If you look closely at the code I add the ORDER BY clause at the end of the query string. That way your query should have the right syntax.